# Sum rows with same values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rows, folium

I have a df like this

[image]

[image]

that in other rows presents some values in common:

[image]

I **want to obtain** just one raw like:

**"Trentino-Alto Adige" -- "Jannsen" -- "12-19" -- 80 -- 38 -- 118 -- 0**

I tried with this two ways and it works:

```
df['Regione'] = df.groupby(['fornitore', 'fascia_anagrafica']).cumcount()
```

or

```
df = df.groupby(['Regione','fornitore','fascia_anagrafica']).agg({'prima_dose': ['sum'],'seconda_dose':['sum']})
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

**But when I put this df through folium** I only receive the same error:

> ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

So the problem is the transformed df.

Someone can suggest me another way to group/merge/sum/agg these rows?

Comment: `df.fillna(0).groupby(['Regione', 'fornitore', 'fascia_anagrafica']).sum()` ??

Comment: Presents a df plotted in a way unusable for folium.